# How to restart HSQLDB(file mode) programmatically after the shutdown?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB(file mode), Spring 4.2.2 , Hibernate 5, JavaFX in my project.

My database is starting in the file-mode.
database.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

        <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <beans:property name="url"
                            value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:/database/statistical_reports;hsqldb.write_delay=true;shutdown=false"/>
            <beans:property name="username" value="sa"/>
            <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
        </beans:bean>

        <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
            <jdbc:script location="classpath*:database/database_schema.sql"/>
        </jdbc:initialize-database>

        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <beans:property name="configLocation" value="hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
            <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
                <beans:list>
                    ... list of hibernate entities...
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </beans:bean>

    </beans:beans>
```

All is working fine and without some problems.

But I need to make some manipulations with database script file and I must to shutdown for my database for a few second. For this, I am using this method and it's also working fine:

```
    public class HibernateUtilDao extends AbstractDao {
        public void shutdownServer(){
            getSession().createSQLQuery("SHUTDOWN").executeUpdate();
        }
        ...
    }
```

And for those manipulations, database.script file must to be released by main thread. But now I need to restart my database somehow.

**Question:** 
How to restart my database from my program? Can you please give some advice or code example for this question?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `file:` databases, after shutdown, you can simply create a new connection to the database and the new connection will open the database automatically. If you create new connections after this, they will connect to the open database.

Comment: Hi fredt. Thank's for all your answers on my questions in HSQLDB themes.

Can you please show some small example... because I am trying to open connection after shutdown, but I am having some kind of those exceptions, 
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: closed

e.t.c.

not shure that I am doing it correctly.

Comment: I don't know the Hibernate details. The message shows the SessionFactory is reusing existing sessions (connections) which no longer work. You need to reset the factory before you restart so it creates new sessions.

Comment: Is there some way to unlock HSQLDB database.script file for some few seconds without the shutdown??? Or maybe a way to change "readonly=false" to "readonly=true" on fly when server is already started?

Comment: No. The .script file is read only at the startup so even if there was a way, your edits would not show. Instead of editing the .script file, use SQL to change the database.