# Is it possible to change HSQLDB mode to read-only on the fly?

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am using HSQLBD in ***file: mode.***

(My usage of the HSQLDB is shown in my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38026321/5331196))

I need to receive a multiple-access to the **database.script** file. 
By default, database is running with option *readonly=false* Here is some information from the official docs:

> Readonly Databases
>
> A file: catalog can be made readonly permanently, or it can be opened
>   as readonly. To make the database readonly, the property, value pair,
>   readonly=true can be added to the .properties file of the database.
>   The SHUTDOWN command must be used to close the database before making
>   this change.
>
> It is also possible to open a normal database as readonly. For this,
>   the property can be included in the URL of the first connection to the
>   database.
>
> With readonly databases, it is still possible to insert and delete
>   rows in TEMP tables.

But I am still not truly understood, is it possible to change this option on the fly, without server shutdown and without restart? If it is possible - can you please give some small code example?

And if not, is there some way to unlock the .script file and get the access for the different threads without the server shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement required to access HSQL internal class. The sample code is written for v2.3.3, it may not work for other version.

```
//import org.hsqldb.*;
//start server
Server.main(new String[]{"-database.0","file:s:/folder/dbname","-dbname.0","dbname","-no_system_exit","true"});

//set DB readonly
Database db = DatabaseManager.lookupDatabaseObject("file:", "s:/folder/dbname");
db.setReadOnly();
//alter connection to readonly
Session[] oa = db.sessionManager.getAllSessions();
for (int i = 0; i < oa.length; i++) {
    if (oa[i].getDatabase() == db) {
        try {
            oa[i].setReadOnly(true);
            oa[i].setReadOnlyDefault(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //the connection is during transaction...
        }
    }
}
//the implementation of Database cannot turn to writable, 
//close it...
db.close(Database.CLOSEMODE_COMPACT);
```